# rpy2/pandas: passing a pandas DataFrame with list type column into R

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I have some R code that takes as input a `data.frame` where one of the columns holds `list` instances in its cells, e.g.:

```
data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"), y=I(list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))))
```

Which looks like

```
  x       y
1 a 1, 2, 3
2 b 4, 5, 6
3 c 7, 8, 9
```

I would like create a similar pandas `DataFrame` in Python and pass it into my R code using the tools in the rpy2 library (version 2.9.4).  However, when I run the following:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

df = DataFrame({
    "x" : ["a", "b", "c"] ,
    "y"  : [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
})

r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)

print(r_df)
```

I get this output:

```
  x y.0.1L y.0.2L y.0.3L y.1.4L y.1.5L y.1.6L y.2.7L y.2.8L y.2.9L

0 a      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9

1 b      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9

2 c      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
```

Of course, the R code was using the "Inhibit" function `I()` in order to be able to hold the `list` instances in the `data.frame` in the first place. Is there some way to express similar intent via the rpy2 interfaces?

Comment: But why are you saving a list in a data frame? What analysis needs this setup? In both pandas and R, save only atomic (not nested) values within columns. Hence why every column in a pandas DataFrame is a pandas Series and every column in a R `data.frame` is an atomic vector!